# Extracting every 7th column, skipping the first 4 column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-extraction

Im looking for a simple code in R that can extra data from a larger data set. How can I retain the first 4 columns (text1, text2, text3, text4) and then every 7th column (column a, column h, etc).

```
example_df <- data.frame(txt1=c(1,2,3,4), txt2=c(1,2,3,4), txt3=c(1,2,3,4), txt4=c(1,2,3,4), a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(1,2,3,4), c=c(1,2,3,4), d=c(1,2,3,4), e=c(1,2,3,4), f=c(1,2,3,4), g=c(1,2,3,4),h=c(1,2,3,4), i=c(1,2,3,4), j=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Which will look like this:

```
  txt1 txt2 txt3 txt4 a b c d e f g h i j
1    1    1    1    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2    2    2    2    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3    3    3    3    3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4    4    4    4    4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

I need to have it look like this

```
  txt1 txt2 txt3 txt4 a h 
1    1    1    1    1 1 1 
2    2    2    2    2 2 2 
3    3    3    3    3 3 3 
4    4    4    4    4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now used to following trick but there might be a faster way of doing this.

```
library(dplyr)
example_df <- df_extracted %>% select(2, 10,    17, 24, 31, 38, 45, 52, 59, 66, 73, 80, 87, 94, 101,    108,    115,    122,    129,    136,    143,    150,    157,    164,    171,    178,    185,    192,    199,    206,    213,    220,    227,    234,    241,    248,    255)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be addressed in a simple way. First step is find out the total number of columns, lets say it is 30. Now the first four is selected by default, so the indices to filter our starts from 5 to 30. From this vector select the ones we need. Prepare a vector of indices and pass to select command in tidyverse. In our case, seq(4,30,7) will give us the following indices=c(4, 11, 18, 25).  We can either filter out 4, or use removing that from our first set as below.

```
library(dplyr)
nc=ncol(example_df)
indices=seq(4,nc,7)

example_df <- df_extracted %>% select(1:3,indices)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! THis saves me time to manually select them!